# Managing git remote tags

Tags: git, git-tag

I have a repository that is an ongoing derivative of another repository. Occasionally the upstream will issue a new tagged release and the derivative may choose to merge and update to be based on that release.

I would have thought, that the process to do that would have been:

```
git remote add upstream <url>
git fetch upstream --tags --prune
git merge upstream/<tagname> myintegrationbranch
```

But that gives me all the tags of the upstream in my own tag list. If my derivative project has a tag that is the same as upstream, tears will happen.

I've done some playing around with the refspec, and the most interesting thing is:

```
[upstream]
    ...
    fetch = refs/tags/*:refs/tags/upstream/*
```

Which gives me duplicates of all the tags, ie `upstream/<tagname>` and `<tagname>`.

My recourse at this stage seems to be of the icky variety where I find the relevant hash for the tag and create a temporary branch from that hash and merge with that, and set up my remote to never pull tags.

Is there a way to sanely manage tags in this particular use case? Or are tags forever bound to be special 'global' objects that cannot be namespaced in any meaningful way?

Answer (score 0):

As shown, you can just leave out `--tags` and get all their tags under your local tag name space as `upstream/<tag>`.  You can refer to these by name: if they had a tag `v7.12` you now have a tag `upstream/v7.12`.  As long as you don't name any of your own tags `upstream/`, you won't collide with theirs.

---

If you do this instead:

```
[upstream]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
    fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/rtags/upstream/*
```

you can still just run `git fetch upstream --prune`.  This will get all their branches into your repository under `refs/remotes/upstream/` (i.e., as remote branches), and all their tags under `refs/rtags/upstream/` (i.e., as something git does not have built in: "remote tags").

Whenever they add or delete tags, the new or removed tags will be copied into your `rtags/` space.

Since this is not built in to git, to check something out by "remote tag" you must spell out the reference:

```
git checkout rtags/upstream/foo
```

If you have local branch `b` and want to merge with "remote tag" `upstream/v7.12`:

```
git checkout b
git merge rtags/upstream/v7.12
```

To list "remote tags", use `git for-each-ref` (you will probably want a custom script, this is just an off-hand example for flavor):

```
#! /bin/sh
# list remote tags from all remotes that have them
show_tag() {
    local rmt=$1 tag=$2 ttype=$3 sha1=$4

    case $ttype in
    commit) echo "$rmt: $tag -> $sha1 (lightweight tag)";;
    tag) echo "$rmt: $tag -> $sha1 (annotated tag)";;
    *) echo "$rmt: $tag -> $sha1 ($ttype)"; # some joker tagged a tree or blob
    esac
}
git for-each-ref refs/rtags |
while read sha1 rtype rname; do
    rname=${rname#refs/rtags/}   # strip off refs/rtags/
    rmt=${rname%%/*}             # name of remote
    rtag=${rname#*/}             # tag on remote
    show_tag $rmt $rtag $rtype $sha1
done
```

I don't use tags very much, not enough to actually have implemented this, but it's pretty straightforward and should just work (aside from the minor annoyance of having to write out `rtags/` all the time).